# RHEL kickstart with external DVDrom drive

Tags: redhat, kickstart

HI 
I've an old Dell poweredge server with an  CDROM drive. I've attached a USB DVDROM and USB stick with my ks.cfg on so I can install RHEL from DVD not loads of CDs :-)

I can boot from the RHEL media in DVDROM and point the installer to the USB ks.cfg. This works but the ks.cfg script has the cdrom keyword in it. The install then stops and asks for the RHEL media to be in the CDROM drive not the DVDROM.

How can I change the ks.cfg so it uses the external DVDROM for the install media not servers builtin cdrom drive ?

I know I can go and rebuild my DVD image to include the ks.cfg , but this is an extra step I dont want to do if I have to.

Regards
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ks=cdrom:<device>
```

As your `ks=` option. The documentation on this is not consistant, so I'm grasping at straws here... Some docs say you specify a device after the colon, others say you specify a file. See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Options for more info.

You might also try

```
ks=hd:<device>:/<file>
```

Comment: The ks= is not the problem , as its reading the ks.cfg . Inside the ks.cfg i have a line whichsays cdrom , but its using the wrong device for the install media

Comment: Oh. What happens if you remove the cdrom line?

Comment: if you can, figure out what device the externam drive is detected as and replace the cdrom line with `harddrive --partition=sdc1 --dir=/tmp/install-tree`. [Example assumes /dev/sdc1 is your external CD's partition] This page http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#install says that `cdrom` always uses the first cd drive.

Comment: Cheers I'll give that try

Comment: If you have no luck, you might also format your DVd using ext2 instead of ISO.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling the internal CD-ROM in BIOS.  As JeffG has already mentioned, Anaconda uses the first device.